# How to get the date column from MySQL database with prepared statement and format it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The query is working but I' having some trouble with prepared statements for the date column only. Everything else is working.

Comment: Hi , 'date'  is in which format here  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y')  ?

Comment: you should not use ',' after '*' try to mention all the column name in query and try

Comment: "won't work"... because? What goes wrong exactly when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should mention column names in query like this and put proper alias in order by clause, i hope you will be passing a date in 'date' or i hope it is a column name inside the table.

```
    select * from 
(SELECT col1,col2, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS convtdate FROM wp_mytb WHERE firstname=%s OR secondname=%s 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1,col2, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS convtdate FROM wp_mytbf WHERE firstname=%s OR secondname=%s
    
     LIMIT 50) a ORDER BY str_to_date(a.convtdate) DESC;
```

Comment: Can you please post the query you are using now ? may be check the values you are passing to  firstname=%s OR secondname=%s

Comment: Date format looks okay for me, just to confirm, can you copy the sql and run it directly into database replacing all your variables to actual values in the query ?

Comment: Or may be you are passing NULL values for  firstname=%s OR secondname=%s  ?

Comment: This suggestion is wrong. Ordering by the `date` column directly will be fine, as that's the real column in the database. ordering by a formatted string version would (assuming it works) be very likely to put the dates in the wrong order.

Comment: @ADyson its a good tip looking at performance, in union all clause i did tried with emp table, it needs alias.

Comment: @Jfrd even if it makes performance better, it will put the results in the wrong order, because the string you're ordering by has days at the start instead of years. So it will be ordered by the first characters of the string, not by the real date

Comment: @ADyson totally agree on it

Comment: have edit the answer to fix the order by date issue

Comment: no way it never disappears infact  you will see more data if second query is generating data, you should give create table and sample data insert scripts, so we can say it for sure. You can edit the question and add it.